# How to create a Git Tag using GitExtensions for Windows?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I want to create a tag for my current version.
I don't see any option for this in the windows context menu...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context menu -> `GitEx Browse`
Right click on commit -> `Create new
    tag`

[image]
[image]